# How to get image baseurl for category icon?

Tags: magento2, image, frontend

I want to setup a method to get image URLs for category icons like `pub/catalog/images/offer.png`

What do I have to do for it?

This is what I am trying to build:

[image]

And this is the URL I need:

```
$vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Phones, Tablets & Accessories', '<img src="http://localhost/kikinben/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/default/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/mobile.png" style="width:20px">Phones, Tablets & Accessories', $vdrawMainMenu);
```

Comment: http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-useful-snippets-for-frontend-developers

Answer (score 0):

In a template, you can use

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Catalog::images/offer.png');
```

If you do it in a block method, use `$this`  instead of `$block`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but it's not working

Comment: $vdrawMainMenu = str_replace('Phones, Tablets & Accessories', '<img src="http://localhost/kikinben/pub/static/frontend/Alothemes/default/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/mobile.png" style="width:20px">Phones, Tablets & Accessories', $vdrawMainMenu);